# goroutine deadlock: In an app that reads from a blockchain and writes to rethinkdb, have

Tags: go, deadlock, channel, goroutine, blockchain

**Okay, so**

My situation is this:  It's been three weeks and some-odd hours since I've become entranced by golang.  I'm working on a blockchain dump tool for steem, and I'm probably going to give a touch of gjson to github.com/go-steem/rpc, the library I currently rely on.  Now, with this said, this question is about the goroutines for my current blockchain reader.  Here it is (sorry a tad on the beefy side, but you'll see the part that I want to pull back into the library, too):

```
    // Keep processing incoming blocks forever.
    fmt.Println("---> Entering the block processing loop")
    for {
        // Get current properties.
        props, err := Client.Database.GetDynamicGlobalProperties()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        // Process blocks.
        for I := uint32(1); I <= props.LastIrreversibleBlockNum; I++ {
            go getblock(I, Client, Rsession)
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

    }

}

func getblock(I uint32, Client *rpc.Client, Rsession *r.Session) {
    block, err := Client.Database.GetBlock(I)
    fmt.Println(I)
    writeBlock(block, Rsession)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func writeBlock(block *d.Block, Rsession *r.Session) {
    //rethinkdb writes
    r.Table("transactions").
        Insert(block.Transactions).
        Exec(Rsession)
    r.Table("blocks").
        Insert(block).
        Exec(Rsession)
}
```

I just made a third edit to this, which was to call the function writeBlock from goroutine getBlock instead of the way I was doing things before.  I'

Comment: It would help if you could isolate the issue and create a reproducible snippet (even better would be a test) without connecting to various resources(i.e. database).  It's also not clear to me what the issue is. Do you run into a specific error (i.e. deadlock) ? If so can you post the error?

Comment: Hm.  So, no I do not-- I did not know that deadlock returns an error.  And, you got it, let me hammer at that code block some to isolate the screwiness.

Thanks!

Comment: In 5 minutes or so I'll post a "cut to the bone (no blockaw) version of the same code.  Thanks.

Comment: If you program is blocked, set `GOTRACEBACK=all` and get a stack trace to see where everything is blocked. You also have goroutines dispatching more goroutines for no discernible reason, so I can be sure what your concurrency plan is here.

Comment: Better to put them both in the iterator, then?

Comment: Let me describe what I think should be happening, but really don't know if is happening:

getblock (this is the performance-limiter-- the blockchain that this connects to reads at about 400 blocks per second, meaning that its ~5m blocks takes about 24 hours with all things left to themselves) should now be able to run more quickly because it's running in paralell, and each time it gets a block, it will feed it to writeblock (writes to rethinkdb)

Comment: And by verbailzing it, something does sound wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so that is now resolved, but this is going to spawn another question, unfortunatley.

I've got the application working with the goroutine, however it hasn't increased performance any.

The way that I got it to work was by not spawning a goroutine from a goroutine and instead calling a plain function, writeBlock from the goroutine "getblock":

```
    fmt.Println("---> Entering the block processing loop")
    for {
        // Get current properties.
        props, err := Client.Database.GetDynamicGlobalProperties()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        // Process blocks.
        for I := uint32(1); I <= props.LastIrreversibleBlockNum; I++ {
            go getblock(I, Client, Rsession)
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

    }

}

func getblock(I uint32, Client *rpc.Client, Rsession *r.Session) {
    block, err := Client.Database.GetBlock(I)
    fmt.Println(I)
    writeBlock(block, Rsession)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func writeBlock(block *d.Block, Rsession *r.Session) {
    //rethinkdb writes
    r.Table("transactions").
        Insert(block.Transactions).
        Exec(Rsession)
    r.Table("blocks").
        Insert(block).
        Exec(Rsession)
}
```